# Installing android studio/android-sdk on arm64 chromebook

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, google-chrome-os

I am trying to install android studio on a Chromebook running arm64, but right off the bat I get an "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted". Fair enough, I go through the wizard and select the location to install through the wizard but before the install starts I get "An error occured while trying to compute required packages".

[image][image]

I also tried downloading android-sdk through apt install android-sdk, but when I go to pick the location nothing happens in the SDK settings, everything is greyed out and the location that I provided (usr/lib/android-sdk) is now gone again.(see photos for process)

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being `running sudo-apt install android-sdk`, moving it to `/home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk` and manually selecting the location.